# Setting variables in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I am trying to use `NSUserDefaults` function to save my game. My question is how to code a variable in `NSUserDefaults` so that I can press a button and the value can add up to the original value.

I have tried the following code to save and to load the method, but failed the numbers can load correctly.

saving

```
- (IBAction)water2:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray * water = [defaults objectForKey:@"water"];

    for(NSNumber * waternumber in water) {
        NSLog(@"Score: %i", [waternumber intValue]);

        NSMutableArray * water = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:[waternumber intValue]+1], nil];

        [defaults setObject:water forKey:@"water"];

    NSLog(@"Score: %i", [waternumber intValue]);

        NSMutableArray * nestedStructure = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"nested"] mutableCopy];

        // Make some change to the structure

        // Add it the whole thing back into NSUserDefaults
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nestedStructure forKey:@"nested"];
        // Synchronize to ensure it's saved
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    } }
```

Loading method:

```
- (IBAction)continue:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray * nestedStructure = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"nested"] mutableCopy];

    // Make some change to the structure

    // Add it the whole thing back into NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nestedStructure forKey:@"nested"];
    // Synchronize to ensure it's saved
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray * water = [defaults objectForKey:@"water"];

    for(NSNumber * waternumber in water) {
        NSLog(@"water: %i", [waternumber intValue]);
    }
```

Comment: One doubt: You are saving an array that has a single object to use defaults with key `"water"`. Why can't you save the object as such?

Comment: Why two variables called `water`?  How do you know the arrays are mutable?

Comment: I know it is strange to do that. But later on I will add more functions and values to it. So i first put it as array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for saving into `NSUserDefaluts`

```
 NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSMutableArray * water = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [defaults  setObject: water forKey:@"water"];
```

for getting in some where

```
 NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSMutableArray *water1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"water"]];
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults always returns immutable objects on modern OSs when built with modern SDKs, and for good reason: it's not set up to handle things being mutated out from under it! You *must* call -mutableCopy on the returned object if you want it to be mutable.

Comment: And don't forget to `synchronize` after modifying something in it.

Comment: i think in the above code just we are saving into userDefaults,we are not modifying the content in it.